# How to generate a P12 file with openSSL?

Tags: windows, command-line, openssl

I'm new to the Command-Line tool and I would like to generate a P12 file, based on a key and a PEM version of an iPhone developer certificate.
This is the command for it:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey mykey.key -in developer_identity.pem -out iphone_dev.p12
```

I [installed openSSL for Windows](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) but don't know the next steps.
Where do I need to open the Command-Line tool for openSSL and where do I need to place the .key and .pem files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where do I need to open the Command-Line tool for openSSL

I believe Shining Light's installer puts the tools in `C:\Win32OpenSSL\bin`. So opens a command prompt there. For some reason, choosing "System Directory" (IIRC) only installs `libeay` in the system directory.

---

> where do I need to place the .key and .pem files?

Hmm... What program needs them? You could try putting them with the program that needs them.

---

> How to generate a P12 file with openSSL?

Your OpenSSL command looks right.

---

Related: using anything other than a Mac or Xcode is usually quite painful. If you want to try on Linux, I suggest you visit the [Jailbreak QA forums](http://www.jailbreakqa.com/). I see Saurik there on occasion.